# Which type of collection is best?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

Wording in my previous question prevented people from answering it.  Regardless to say, I can do what I need to do.  My ultimate concern is which option is optimal?

I am traversing the entire Active Directory for the domain and filtering it down by people/users.

I then need to throw this information into a collection.

I know I can do it with

```
List<Users>  // Create a model with the information i need and populate it.
Dictionary<string, List<Users>> // add a list of users to the string/department
Dictionary<string, Users> // struct or class
Lookup<string, Users>
```

I'm more looking for the optimal way, as going the Active Directory can be slow by it self I'm looking to optimize my code in other areas.

I only need the department stored a single time, and each department can have many different users.

What is the most optimal method to choose in this instance?

Edit Addition:

The only reason I need this specific code is for a specific page which will eventually allow me to loop through the contents and build out a drop down list.  This code will not be used any where else.

Comment: `which option is optimal` is most likely not an appropriate question for stackoverflow since it cannot be answered _correctly_. If you want to ask subjective questions ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. If you want to improve your code ask it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: "Optimal" for what?  Querying the users by department?  Querying the users by some other field?   What are you actually trying to do and what bottleneck do you think you are fixing?

Comment: @KirkWoll I edited my response, but probably not before you read it.  I am looking specifically at speed here since the active directory is slow by itself.  Any way I can use the fastest resources in other parts of my code to compensate the better.  I know each collection can do certain things faster or slower than other collections.  I will need to loop through this collection, grabbing the department and each user in the department and throwing that into a drop down list grouped by department.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't/dont think this question is subjective.  There are benchmarks out there for each collection type.  So optimal at least when comparing speed is definitely a question that can be answered down to the miliseconds.

Comment: If Active Directory is the bottleneck then what does it matter if the *fast* part of the code is *slower than it could be*? If you want to lose weight, don't start by trimming your nails.

Comment: @EricLippert using anything other than Active Directory currently is not an option.  So if my active directory call takes <20 seconds> and traversing my list could take anywhere from <1-3 seconds> depending on the collection type and method in which it is used.  I would choose to trim my nails for those couple extra seconds. ;)

Comment: The trick then is to choose the data structure that is optimized *for the operations you're going to be performing on it*. A hash table, for example, is optimal for searching for an exact match, but highly non-optimal for searching for a partial match. An array list is optimized for inserting at the end but highly non-optimal for inserting at the beginning.

Comment: @EricLippert these are the things I need to learn and thanks for taking a bit of extra time to help me.  The only thing I need this collection for is to loop through it and create a drop down list of every single user separated by `<optgroup = "department">`.  I don't have to add items in any specific order, but they must be easily categorized by department.  I'm guessing a `Lookup` is going to be my best match, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If all you're going to do is loop through it, a list makes sense.  Also as an aside, programming assistance from @EricLippert - isn't StackOverflow great?!

Comment: @KrisC I was leaning toward an ILookup, but from all the advice here I'm thinking I will do a List as recommended.  And yes I love Stack overflow.  I always bring my questions/concerns here, it had made me such a better developer than I would been on my own.

Comment: @KrisC I just read up on who EricLippert is.  I always feel honored by all of the support/help but now I feel a bit extra honored. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A List is going to be faster when writing or accessing by index or scanning.

A Dictionary is going to be faster when accessing an item by its key (O(1) instead of O(N) or O(log N) in the list).

If you are trying to add all users to a drop down box go with `List<User>`.

If you are going to add all departments to a drop down box and add the users from that department to a different drop down use `Dictionary<Department, List<User>>` and maybe do some profiling to see if it makes sense to have a separate list of departments.

If you are going to recreate the collection every time the page is accessed you will need to do some profiling with realish data to see which performs better.

Edit:
Based on your update how about something like

```
class Department
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<User> Users {get;set;}
}

List<Department> departments;

foo()
{
   foreach(department in departments)
   {
       // emit optgroup
       foreach(user in department.Users)
       {
           // emit option
       }
       // emit /optgroup
   }
}
```

or better yet cache the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thanks Yaur, what if I will need to access the information.  Create one single drop down list, the reason department will be needed is I will use `<optgroup = 'department'>` so people who use the dropdown list can easily see which user is in which department.

Comment: Thank you very much Yaur, I think I will go the List path as you recommended.  I was trying to look up information on `ILookup` but wasn't finding much luck.  I understand Lists much better.  I will also look up info on caching the results as well I think that will be beneficial to what im doing.  Thank you again.